AWS Console Fleet Manager errors when attempting to preview file from EC2 Instance's File System
I have accessed the AWS Fleet Manager service in the AWS Console and have navigated to an EC2 Instance's File System. After selecting a .log file I would like to interrogate I select the Action dropdown. From here I select View and attempt to either a) View File As Text or b) Tail File. Both options lead to a red bar appearing at the top of the screen with the message 'An Unexpected error has occurred'.
I have attempted to navigate to the EC2 Instance's file system through a terminal window down to the VAR/log directory to see if AWS has written any more detailed messages but nothing of any value can be found there.
Does anyone know where I can find more detailed information about this error to get this feature working?
screenshot from AWS Fleet Manager
